# passportjs custom callback 200

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, passport-local

I am using angularjs and jade templating for my client side.  And node and express on the server side.  I recently added passport authentication and have the local strategy working fine when the login is attempted with valid credentials.  It's the error cases that I'm having trouble with.  I have implemented the custom callback to get my error messages to bubble back to the client.   Now I get the error messages but the status gets set to 200 somewhere, instead of the 401 I expect.

```
// login route
app.post("/api/login", function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate("local", function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        } 
        if (user === false) {
            res.status = 401;
            res.send(info.message);
        } else {
             res.json({success:"User logged in"});
        }
     })(req, res, next);
});
```

and this is the angular controller that submits the login request:

```
var loginObj = {email: $scope.login.email,
                password:$scope.login.password};

            $http.post("/api/login", loginObj)
            .success(function(data, status) {
                console.log("successful login");
                console.log("data = " + JSON.stringify(data));
                console.log("status = " + status);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                console.log("error logging in.");
                console.log("error = " + JSON.stringify(error));
                $scope.error = error;
            });
```

So, suppose I have a password mismatch... the error in my validation routine sets my error message to "Invalid password, please try again." But what I see on the console is:

```
successful login
data = "Invalid password, please try again."
status = 200
```

I'm not resetting the status anywhere else.  How is it getting set to 200?  What am I doing wrong?  Sorry, I'm a relative newbie to node and angular, so any help would really be appreciated. I know I'm not understanding some key point, I just can't figure out what. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to add when I change the server side to look like:
    app.post("/api/login", passport.authenticate("local"));
Then I get the 401 status but of course don't see my error messages.  error just says "Unauthorized"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `res.status(401)`, not `res.status = 401`.
`res.status()` is a function.

Comment: Oh good grief, I knew this. Thank you.  This is why I shouldn't be coding at night.

Comment: You're welcome. I hear you, but coding in broad day light makes it too easy though :)